# How to use a dictionary to clean a column that contains a list of keywords in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following column inside a dataset (sample exported as a dictionary)

```
'amenities': {1913: '[Cooking basics, Hair dryer, Fire extinguisher, Microwave, Refrigerator, Dedicated workspace, Pocket wifi, Lock on bedroom door, Dishes and silverware, Private living room, Essentials, Free street parking, Oven, Paid parking off premises, Hot water, Paid washer  In building, Extra pillows and blankets, Hangers, Backyard, Shampoo, TV with standard cable, Stove, Heating, First aid kit, Self check-in, Iron, Smoke alarm, Lockbox, Bed linens, Kitchen, Patio or balcony, Coffee maker, Crib, Wifi]',
  11765: '[Cooking basics, Hair dryer, Courtyard view, Coffee maker: drip coffee maker, Standalone high chair - available upon request, Outdoor furniture, Fire extinguisher, Coffee, Microwave, Shared backyard  Fully fenced, Refrigerator, Dishes and silverware, TV, Essentials, Free washer  In unit, Heating - split type ductless system, Oven, Hot water, Extra pillows and blankets, Toaster, Hangers, Long term stays allowed, Trash compactor, Shower gel, Private patio or balcony, Clothing storage: closet, Cleaning products, Drying rack for clothing, City skyline view, Shampoo, Central air conditioning, Garden view, Freezer, Hot water kettle, Host greets you, Dishwasher, Babysitter recommendations, Wifi, Elevator, Private entrance, First aid kit, Baby bath - available upon request, Safe, AC - split type ductless system, Room-darkening shades, Iron, Smoke alarm, Bed linens, Wine glasses, Kitchen, Body soap, Dining table, Sun loungers, Crib, Stainless steel electric stove, Conditioner, Pack n play/Travel crib - available upon request, Free parking on premises]',
  9320: '[Air conditioning, Free street parking, Fire extinguisher, Dedicated workspace, First aid kit, Paid street parking off premises]'}
```

what I am trying to do is to use a dictionary that I have manually created (see example below, the full dataset is more that 150 entries) to clean the this column.

```
{'Silver refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Electronia refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Kunft refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'com zona de congelao refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'BEKO  refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Teka  refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Desconhecida refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Pequeno com espao de congelao refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'SMEG  refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Indiferente refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'ORIMA refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Hotpoint refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'JOCEL refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Frigorico com congelador de encastre - BALAY refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Grote Koelkast refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'SMEG refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Samsung refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Americano refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Candy  refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Bosch refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Lg  refrigerator': 'Refrigerator',
 'Resort access': 'Resort access'}
```

In particular what I am trying to do is to check if the keyword of the dictionary is inside the list and replace it with the value of the dictionary.

I wrote the following function but it does not work. the output is a list of list where each list is simply a letter. I tried to run the same function with a simple example and it work correctly. What I am doing wrong?

```
def clean_words(word_list, replacement_dict):
    cleaned_words = [replacement_dict.get(word, word) for word in word_list]
    return cleaned_words

df['amenities'] = df['amenities'].apply(clean_words, replacement_dict=replacement_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have a list but a **string**. Unfortunately, as the inner strings are not quoted, this is not a valid representation of a python list and you can't use `ast.literal_eval`.

One option is to `split`:

```
def clean_words(word_list, replacement_dict):
    cleaned_words = '[%s]' % ', '.join(
                            [replacement_dict.get(word, word) for word
                             in word_list[1:-1].split(', ')])
    return cleaned_words

df['amenities']= df['amenities'].apply(clean_words, replacement_dict=replacement_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked out. I was confused if I had list or not because every time I was looking to the data I just saw the list. Just only when I export as a dictionary the ``` ' ``` was showing and I thought it was for the dictionary